# Prove $(\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ with $d(x,y)=|\tan x-\tan y|$ is complete

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I was trying to prove that this metric space is complete Prove $(\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ with $d(x,y)=|\tan x-\tan y|$ is complete.

Attempt let $x_n$ be cauchy in the metric space with respect to the metric $d$. Then for $\epsilon>0$  there is an $N$ such that $n,m \geq N$ $\implies$ $|\tan (x_n)-\tan(x_m)|<\epsilon$. Then $|\tan(x_n)|$ is a cauchy sequence of real numbers, and converges to $x \in \mathbb{R}$. So $x_n$ converges to a $y \in (\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$. So the metric space is complete.

Comments: I am having quite some difficulty determining the validity of the last few sentences. Can anyone say if this is correct? If not how should I approach this?

Comment: YOu need to show that if $\tan(x_n)\to x$ then $x_n\to \arctan(x)=:y$ (in fact it is equivalent).

Comment: @TitoEliatron can you please help on how I should show this?Do I use the continuity of $\tan$?

Comment: Continuity of $\arctan$

Comment: @TitoEliatron since $x_n \rightarrow x \implies \arctan(x_n) \rightarrow \arctan x=y$? I do not understand how the $\tan(x_n)$ is used here

Comment: NO. Since ·$\tan x_n\to x$, $x_n=\arctan(\tan x_n)\to\arctan(x)$.

Comment: @TitoEliatron thanks

Answer (score 1):

The map $\arctan\colon\Bbb R\longrightarrow\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)$ is an isometry if in $\Bbb R$ you consider the usual metric and in $\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)$ you consider the metric $d$. So, since $\Bbb R$ is complete with respect to the usual metric, then so is $\left(\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right),d\right)$.